How does larger change in KE lead to Oberth effect (or is it something else)?
(I know, there are similar questions here already, but not identical, and I haven't found a satisfying answer on any of them yet. If you do find one, let me know)
In short, I still don't get how the commonly used explanations for Oberth effect explain anything. By that I mean "you get more kinetic energy from a burn" and "more of the kinetic energy ends up in your rocket" when moving faster, based on KE = 1/2m × v^2. Both of these sentences make sense to me in isolation, but how does this allow more efficient maneuvers? I assume it might be related to some further factors, like the celestial object I'd be passing by, but besides that I have no idea what's actually going on.
For more context: I tried imagining a 60kg astronaut on Earth's orbit throwing a 5kg bowling ball at 12 m/s, imparting a Δv of 1 m/s on himself (m1a1=m2a2 ->(t1=t2) -> m1v1=m2v2). First starting at rest, then at 100 m/s (relative to, idk, something). Using KE=1/2m×v^2, the astronaut did gain more KE the second time, and he also gained more than the ball, instead of gaining several times less than it. But in both cases he's still throwing that same ball the same way and always gaining 1 m/s of Δv, as the law of action and reaction dictates, I see no reason why that wouldn't be the case. As far as I know it's the Δv you can impart on yourself that determines what maneuver you can do, the KE and the way it scales seems almost irrelevant here yet it's so often used as an obvious explanation. What am I missing here?


how does this allow more efficient maneuvers? … What am I missing here?

What you are missing is the gravity well. You cannot use the Oberth effect without a gravity well.
Going down to a certain altitude gives you a fixed amount $\Delta KE$, not $\Delta v$. Then at the bottom you do the rocket burn, which gives you a fixed $\Delta v$. Because of your speed, you gain a lot of $KE$. Finally, as you leave the gravity well it removes the $\Delta KE$ that it added earlier. But that leaves you with a larger $\Delta v$ than what you put in at the bottom.
If you think about it in terms of impulse, you spend less time coming out of the gravity well than you spend going in. So the gravitational impulse is greater going in than it is going out.

The Oberth effect is a little surprising, since burning some quantity of fuel will always release the same amount of chemical energy no matter where or when you do it. The key is where that energy winds up - either as kinetic energy or the rocket, or as kinetic energy of the exhaust. As you go faster, a larger proportion of the fuel's stored energy winds up in the rocket, not the exhaust.
Analyzing KE can be a little tricky since it depends on the reference frame, as there is no such thing as an "absolute velocity". The same fuel burned can result in different KE changes depending on your frame of reference, so it's best not to compare KE between frames. Delta-v, on the other hand, will be the same in any reference frame.

The rocket having more KE, at least relative to that planet it's flying by, is nothing new to me. But the Δv is still the same and I still don't know why the KE even matters. Can you describe the physical effect that greater KE has on the rocket? Like, it's all well and good it has more than the exhaust from the planets point of view, but what does it actually do?
